# How to make this algorithm faster?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am trying to come up with the following algorithm:

The input is unsigned integer number.
The output is the size of the array of unordered pairs of unsigned integers, which, when multiplied, give a number less then or equal to the input.

I have one naive implementation working, but it is way too slow for my purpose (compl. O(n^2), please correct me if I am wrong). My question is: how to make it faster?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool notInYet(int t[][1], int mi, int ma, int m) {
    bool val = true;
    for(int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        if(t[i][0] == mi && t[i][1] == ma)
            val = false;
    return val;
}

int main() {
    int n, m;
    int t[100000][1];
    cin >> n;
    m = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        for(int j = 1; j*i <= n && j <= i; j++) {
            if(notInYet(t, j, i, m)) {
                t[m][0] = j;
                t[m][1] = i;
                //cout << "t[" << m << "] = (" << t[m][0] << ", " << t[m][1] << ")" << endl;
                m++;
            } 
        }
    }
    cout << m << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Take a closer look. `t[m][1]`

Comment: Belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @chris What is wrong with it? Is there something about 2D arrays I am missing?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for a code review.

Comment: Code review would be for style or best practices. Asking for perf advice falls under a slightly different category.

Comment: You might ask a version of this question, minus the code, on mathoverflow.com.  "The number of integers whose product is <= n" feels like a natural combinatorial question that has some well-known answer, in which case you might be able to just look up the standard procedure for computing it.  Possibly this would avoid the brute-force search you're doing here; or you might find out that this is essentially the best one can do.

Comment: @mirgee: Your definition of `int t[100000][1];` is incorrect. When you define an array of `x` elements the valid indexes are `0..x-1`. If you want to use `t[m][0]` and `t[m][1]` you must define it as `int t[100000][2];` so the last dimension will be two elements.

Comment: @MSN Quote from CR-Helpcenter: "If you are looking for feedback on a specific working piece of code from your project in the following areas: Best practices and design pattern usage, Security issues, **Performance**, Correctness in unanticipated cases
then you are in the right place!" Emphasis mine.

Comment: @BaummitAugen, maybe, but it's not an official stackexchange site yet.

Comment: @factotum I think I should say there is no closed form for the result. However you face the problem, you have to find the number of divisors of an integer (satisfying certain conditions even) which is, by nature, a task for an algorithm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it should be something like that - pseudocode:

```
int counter = 0;
for int i = 1 to sqrt(input), i++ {
    if (input % i == 0) counter++;
}
```

counter is an answer if you need unique pairs, otherwise you need to multiply it by 2 (and sub 1 if input % sqrt(input) == 0)

Comment: This is almost precisely my first idea. Because of some brain malfunction though, I halved the root (why??), hence wrong results and I started complicating it... This, of course, works well a very fast :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading correctly @jauser's algorithm doesn't get what you want.

If the target is 5, then the pairs are (1,1)(1,2)(1,3)(1,4)(1,5)(2,2). So the answer is 6.  His algorithm will produce 1 because 5 mod 1 == 0, but not mod 2.

In general, if the target is `n`, then you know (1,k) is a counted pair for all k from 1 to n.  There are n - 1 + 1 = n of these.  Now you have (2,k) for k from 2 to floor(n/2) (skip 1 because your pairs are unordered). There are n/2-2+1 of these. Continue this through (j,k) for j= floor(sqrt(n)). Putting this is pseudocode

```
count = 0;
for j in 1 .. floor(sqrt(n))
  count += floor(n / j) - j + 1;
```

Maybe there is even some clever series solution that gets this to a constant time calculation.

Am I missing something in the problem?

Comment: You have to run his algorithm for each "input" between one and target, then the result is correct :)

Comment: @mirgee  Okay, but it's O(n^2) rather than O(n).  And I think a O(1) solution is possible.  I guess you don't care about run time.

Comment: Yes, I do! That's why I posted the question. I believe O(n) solution must exist and I haven't tried yours, but it looks right. On the other hand, existence of O(1) would be a miracle in my eyes! I don't think that's possible, because there is no way to find number divisors in a constant time. Do you have any idea how to achieve O(1) complexity? I would love to hear it, really!

Comment: @mirgee Yes my solution is O(n) and gives correct answers if I'm reading the problem right.  For O(1), you don't need to find divisors.  You just need a way of summing floor(n/j) for j = 1 to m where n and m are known.

Comment: Yes. Too bad there is no closed form for n-th harmonic number neither.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are spending a lot of time effectively calculating the following per `i`:

```
j= n/i;
```

So if you just do that you reduce the complexity to O(`n`). You can halve it also since the list will contain both `(i, j)` and `(j, i)` when `i!=j`, but that won't reduce the overall complexity.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am not sure I understand, however. Not considering j*i = n will not give me the answer I am looking for (...less or equal), and I don't think it would affect the overall complexity. But again, maybe I just don't get your point.